# How To Have Multiple Repos With A Dispatch.Yaml File?

Tags: google-app-engine

So I have a problem. I have multiple repos with dispatch.yaml files in each like so:

Repo/Website A -> dispatch.yaml

```
  url: website-a.com/*
  service: website-a-web-app
```

Repo/Website B -> dispatch.yaml

```
  url: website-b.com/*
  service: website-b-web-app
```

Repo/Website C -> dispatch.yaml

```
  url: website-c.com/*
  service: website-c-web-app
```

But it seems like, when I push up for website A it erases website B and C's domain mapping properties. So it looks something like this:

Before:

website A -> website-a.com - website-a-web-app

website B -> website-b.com - website-b-web-app

website C -> website-c.com - website-c-web-app

After Deploying Website A:

website A -> website-a.com

website B -> default-website.com - default

website C -> default-website.com - default

Here is my cloud build deployment script, am I doing something wrong? If not how can I handle this use case as its not very convenient to have to copy these into each repo every time one changes or I add a service.

```
timeout: 1200s
steps:
- name: 'node:14.20.0'
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']

- name: 'node:14.20.0'
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install', '-g', '@angular/cli']

- name: 'node:14.20.0'
  entrypoint: npm
  args: [ 'run', 'build:$_BUILD_COMMAND', "--prod" ]

- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy"]

- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy", "dispatch.yaml"]
```

Comment: There is one dispatch.yaml per project.  It is used by all your services.

Comment: @minou, so if thats the case how do people deploy multiple services? Is there any type of strategy I can follow that doesn't involve me having to update every dispatch.yaml or have mono repo for every one of my angular apps? Thanks for your help

Comment: ```so if thats the case how do people deploy multiple services?```. Multiple services are all linked to the same project. You can deploy each service separately (and their files can be in different folders on your hard drive) but the ```dispatch.yaml``` is for the entire project. Think of it this way - your ```dispatch.yaml``` is responsible for routing incoming traffic to your different services.

Comment: @NoCommandLine, Thanks for the help so far. so what do you think is the best way to deploy different services using different repos? Should I keep the dispatch.yaml in an entirely separate repo? Im just lost as we have CI/CD set up and I would have to pull a different repo every time something happened on one of the website repos.